# Subsections dont show up in contents pane of pdf

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I would like sub- and subsubsections to be listed in the contents pane of my pdf document, but only the sections are showing up.    Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I can click on the arrow to see the subsections, but I'd like them to show up without having to click.     Thanks for any help!

Comment: `bookmarkopenlevel=2, bookmarksopen` as an option to hyperref

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I searched for an answer but missed this one